# Reformat USB with unrecognized partition

Tags: windows-7, usb, partitioning

I have a USB drive, and I used Debian Linux to flash it with a bootable version of Linux. However, now Windows won't recognize it anymore. It shows up in Disk Management like this:
[image]
But if I try to create or remove partitions, the options are grayed out.

The drive will not show up in Windows Explorer. How can I reformat it so that I can use it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 step-by-step instructions. Open command prompt *as administrator*

Start `diskpart`
[image: dp001]

List volumes
[image: dp002]

Select volume associated with USB drive (*optional, do this only if drive letter is currently assigned*)
[image: dp003]

Remove associated drive letter (*optional, do this only if drive letter is currently assigned*)
[image: dp004]

Clean (removes all partition data)
[image: dp005]

Create new partition
[image: dp006]

Format partition (replace `fat32` with `exfat` or `ntfs` if you like)
[image: dp007]

Assign drive letter
[image: dp008]

You're done ;-)
[image: dp009]

Comment: Great, thorough answer! I actually ended up using diskpart yesterday but I must have not gone through all the necessary steps because windows denied me permission to access my drive. So I hard formatted it (since it showed up in explorer) and now it works.